# How to make whole row unique in Django

Tags: django, django-models

So I have a User model and a Community model. Now in order to check if user has joined a commity I have a UserJoinedCommunity model. It has `user` and `community` field. Like so:

```py
class UserJoinedCommunity(models.Model):
    """DB Model for users joined communities"""
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    community = models.ForeignKey(Community, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user.username}|{self.community.name}"
```

So what I want is to make a whole row unique so user can't "join community multiple times". So if users id is 3 and he joins community with id 5 it will created a record ex.`{user: 3, community: 5}`. I want that to be unique so it can't be created again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is `unique_together`.

```
class UserJoinedCommunity(models.Model):
    """DB Model for users joined communities"""
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    community = models.ForeignKey(Community, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ['user', 'community']

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user.username}|{self.community.name}"
```

Note that this will create a constraint in the database. This is not application level constraint. In other words, you'll still have to handle the IntegrityError yourself.

[More info here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/options/#unique-together)